# Radial progress bar with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I want to make this code a circle progress bar that works with radio buttons, this one is a horizontal progress bar. My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    $('[name*=answers]').click(function() {
        var totalChecked = 0;
        var totalRadioGroups = 0;
        var previousName = '';
        $.each($('[name*=answers]'), function(index, value) {
            var radioName = $(this).attr('name');
            var radioId = this.id;

            if (previousName != radioName) {
                totalRadioGroups++;
            }
            if ($('#' + radioId).is(':checked')) {
                totalChecked++;
            }
            previousName = radioName;
        });
        var percentage = (totalChecked / totalRadioGroups) * 100;
        $('#progressbar').progressbar('value', percentage);
        $('#percentage').html(percentage.toFixed(2) + "%");
    });

});
```

```html
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<div id="percentage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some researches about the circle progress bars and the easiest solution that i came up with is; drawing on canvas. The link is a [**DEMO**](http://cr8code.co/editor.php?workid=ee6c2737c676594ff7ffbefcbe224b01) where you select how many section you are going to divide your progress bar and upon clicking next it will start goin on with each click.
Belive me, this is the easiest way i have found and you can customize it according to your needs.

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="220" height="220"></canvas>
<br>
<br>
<button id="minus">-</button> <span id="num">0</span> <button id="plus">+</button>
<br><br>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS

```
#myCanvas{
  border:none;
}
```

JS

```
var f = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){

    var n = $('#num').text();

  $('#minus').click(function(){
   if(n>0){
     n--;
     $('#num').text(n);
   }
  });

  $('#plus').click(function(){
     n++;
     $('#num').text(n);
  });

  $('#next').click(function(){
    if(n == 0){
      draw(2);
    } else {
    var x = 2/n;
    x= f+x;
    draw(x);
    }
  });

});

function draw(e){
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
  ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,e*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
  f = e;
};
```